# Bad operand types for binary operator '*'

Tags: java

I'm getting the error:

```
error: bad operand types for binary operator '*'
if ((monthD * dayD).equals("yearD"))    
            ^
first type:  String
second type: String
```

The point of the code is to see if the month and date equal the year when multiplied.

Here is my code:

```
// Month
String monthD;
System.out.print("What is the month? (For example, August would inserted as '08') ");
monthD = userInput.nextLine();

// Day
String dayD;
System.out.print("What is the day? (For example, the 10th of the month is inserted as '10') ");
dayD = userInput.nextLine();

// Year
String yearD;
System.out.print("What is the year? (For example, 1998 is inserted as '98') ");
yearD = userInput.nextLine();

// Is this date magic?
if ((monthD * dayD).equals("yearD"))
{ 
    System.out.print("This date is magic!");
} 
else
{ 
    System.out.print("This date is not magic!");
}
```

Comment: Why do you read your input as String when you want int?

Comment: your logic is wrong as well, first check what you want to compare.

Comment: I tried int and double as well and it didn't work, this is just the last option I tried.  What else should I do?

Answer (score 0):

You cant have `String` datatypes for '*' (multiplication) purposes.
Instead use an `int` type.

Comment: I've tried so many different variations, string was just the last one I tried.  What can I use?

Comment: use 'int'
and in your 'if' loop, remove the double quotes around the '  .euals(yearD)   '

Comment: or simply use




"
if (monthD * dayD == yearD){...your code...}
else {...your code...}
"

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `Integer.parseInt(String)` to convert the string to an integer. Surround with try/catch to check for not real integers. And *what* are you even trying to do, just use `new Date()` from java.util.Date to get the date

Comment: I'm sorry I haven't gotten that far in my class I don't think it has to be that complicated, no offense.  I just need to see if the month x day = year

Comment: [This is a gist i just made](https://gist.github.com/ramidzkh/5c5a278941fbebe7d1221de878857ef4)